# Create JavaFX self-contained application (with custom JDK) in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

As the title suggests, I would like to create a self-contained JavaFX application, using an other JDK/JRE than the system default. Netbeans is capable of doing this, however, I do not yet know how to do this in Eclipse.

By using [e(fx)clipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html), you are able to generate a build file (`build.fxbuild`). With Netbeans, the following needs to be added to the `build.xml` to include the custom JDK in the jar (this is just the example from [Oracle](https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/native_packaging_for_javafx)):

```
<target name="-post-jfx-deploy">
   <fx:deploy width="${javafx.run.width}" height="${javafx.run.height}" 
             nativeBundles="all"
             outdir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" outfile="${application.title}">
      <fx:application name="${application.title}" mainClass="${javafx.main.class}"/>
      <fx:resources>
          <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" includes="BrickBreaker.jar"/>
      </fx:resources>
      <fx:info title="${application.title}" vendor="${application.vendor}"/>
    </fx:deploy>          
 </target>
```

So, is this possible in Eclipse? And if so, how can I bundle the JDK with the jar?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT: Added build output from console**

I'm working on Mac OSX 10.10.1, Yosemite.

```
Buildfile: /Users/RobinTrietsch/EclipseProjects/octocash-updater/OctoCash Updater/build/build.xml
setup-staging-area:
   [delete] Deleting directory /Users/RobinTrietsch/EclipseProjects/octocash-updater/OctoCash Updater/build/externalLibs
   [delete] Deleting directory /Users/RobinTrietsch/EclipseProjects/octocash-updater/OctoCash Updater/build/project
   [delete] Deleting directory /Users/RobinTrietsch/EclipseProjects/octocash-updater/OctoCash Updater/build/projectRefs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/RobinTrietsch/EclipseProjects/octocash-updater/OctoCash Updater/build/externalLibs
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /Users/RobinTrietsch/EclipseProjects/octocash-updater/OctoCash Updater/build/externalLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/RobinTrietsch/EclipseProjects/octocash-updater/OctoCash Updater/build/project
     [copy] Copying 4 files to /Users/RobinTrietsch/EclipseProjects/octocash-updater/OctoCash Updater/build/project
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/RobinTrietsch/EclipseProjects/octocash-updater/OctoCash Updater/build/projectRefs
do-compile:
   [delete] Deleting directory /Users/RobinTrietsch/EclipseProjects/octocash-updater/OctoCash Updater/build/build
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/RobinTrietsch/EclipseProjects/octocash-updater/OctoCash Updater/build/build/src
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/RobinTrietsch/EclipseProjects/octocash-updater/OctoCash Updater/build/build/libs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/RobinTrietsch/EclipseProjects/octocash-updater/OctoCash Updater/build/build/classes
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /Users/RobinTrietsch/EclipseProjects/octocash-updater/OctoCash Updater/build/build/libs
     [copy] Copying 4 files to /Users/RobinTrietsch/EclipseProjects/octocash-updater/OctoCash Updater/build/build/src
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/RobinTrietsch/EclipseProjects/octocash-updater/OctoCash Updater/build/build/classes
     [copy] Copying 3 files to /Users/RobinTrietsch/EclipseProjects/octocash-updater/OctoCash Updater/build/build/classes
init-fx-tasks:
do-deploy:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /Users/RobinTrietsch/EclipseProjects/octocash-updater/OctoCash Updater/build/dist/libs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/RobinTrietsch/EclipseProjects/octocash-updater/OctoCash Updater/build/build/classes/META-INF
No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.
Bundler Mac Application Image skipped because of a configuration problem: Main application jar is missing.  
Advice to fix: Make sure to use fx:jar task to create main application jar.
Bundler DMG Installer skipped because of a configuration problem: Main application jar is missing.  
Advice to fix: Make sure to use fx:jar task to create main application jar.
Bundler PKG Installer skipped because of a configuration problem: Main application jar is missing.  
Advice to fix: Make sure to use fx:jar task to create main application jar.
Bundler Mac App Store Ready Bundler skipped because of a configuration problem: Main application jar is missing.  
Advice to fix: Make sure to use fx:jar task to create main application jar.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2 seconds
```

**EDIT: Added generated build.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="OctoCash Updater" default="do-deploy" basedir="."  xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
<target name="init-fx-tasks">
    <path id="fxant">
        <filelist>
            <file name="${java.home}\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar"/>
            <file name="${java.home}\lib\jfxrt.jar"/>
        </filelist>
    </path>

    <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"      
        uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
        classpathref="fxant"/>
</target>
<target name="setup-staging-area">
    <delete dir="externalLibs" />
    <delete dir="project" />
    <delete dir="projectRefs" />

    <mkdir dir="externalLibs" />

    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="/Users/RobinTrietsch/EclipseProjects/octocash-updater/OctoCash Updater/lib">
            <filename name="gson-2.3.1.jar"/>   
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <mkdir dir="project" />
    <copy todir="project">
        <fileset dir="/Users/RobinTrietsch/EclipseProjects/octocash-updater/OctoCash Updater">
            <include name="src/**" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <mkdir dir="projectRefs" />
</target>
<target name='do-compile'>
    <delete dir="build" />
    <mkdir dir="build/src" />
    <mkdir dir="build/libs" />
    <mkdir dir="build/classes" />

    <!-- Copy project-libs references -->
    <copy todir="build/libs">
        <fileset dir="externalLibs">
            <include name="gson-2.3.1.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <!-- Copy project references -->

    <!-- Copy project sources itself -->
    <copy todir="build/src">
        <fileset dir="project/src">
            <include name="**/*"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <javac includeantruntime="false" source="1.8" target="1.8" srcdir="build/src" destdir="build/classes" encoding="UTF-8">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="build/libs">
                <include name="*"/>
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </javac>

    <!-- Copy over none Java-Files -->
    <copy todir="build/classes">
    <fileset dir="project/src">
        <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
    </fileset>
    </copy>


</target>
<target name="do-deploy" depends="setup-staging-area, do-compile, init-fx-tasks">
    <delete file="dist"/>
    <delete file="deploy" />

    <mkdir dir="dist" />
    <mkdir dir="dist/libs" />

    <copy todir="dist/libs">
        <fileset dir="externalLibs">
            <include name="*" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>


    <fx:resources id="appRes">
        <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="OctoCash Updater.jar"/>
        <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="libs/*"/>
    </fx:resources> 

    <fx:application id="fxApplication"
        name="OctoCash"
        mainClass="octocash.updater.Main"
        toolkit="fx"
    />

    <mkdir dir="build/classes/META-INF" />



    <fx:jar destfile="dist/OctoCash Updater.jar">
        <fx:application refid="fxApplication"/>
        <fileset dir="build/classes">
        </fileset>
        <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>

        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="Barotech"/>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="OctoCash"/>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="1.0"/>
            <attribute name="JavaFX-Feature-Proxy" value="None"/>
        </manifest>
    </fx:jar>


    <mkdir dir="deploy" />
    <!-- Need to use ${basedir} because somehow the ant task is calculating the directory differently -->
    <fx:deploy
        embedJNLP="false"
        extension="false"
        includeDT="false"
        offlineAllowed="true"
        outdir="${basedir}/deploy"
        outfile="OctoCash Updater" nativeBundles="all"
        updatemode="background" >

        <fx:info title="OctoCash Updater" vendor="Barotech"/>
        <fx:application refId="fxApplication"/>
        <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>
    </fx:deploy>


</target>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I just had this problem. I had a hard time finding the solution. By reading a lot of different stuff I managed to find a solution. I use Netbeans but it should work for Eclipse.

In Netbeans I browsed the files in the project until I found a file named project.properties.  I then opened the file and went to the line that starts with dist.jar=. Next I rename the jar file so that it has the exact same name as my project main file.

In my case my main was name something like helloworld and my dist.jar was name hello world.jar  I renamed it helloworld.jar and saved the file. I then rebuilt the project and recreated the native installers. It worked fine after that.

Answer (score 1):

What did you select as Packaging Format? If you select "All" it will generate a self-contained installer which has the JRE included.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've selected the option 'all', but I still get the same message in the console: "No base JDK. Package will use system JRE." followed by "Make sure to use fx:jar task to create main application jar.". Any ideas?

Comment: So does it stop after this message? I get the JDK info as well on OS-X. If you shared a sample somewhere I'd take a look.

Comment: I've added the output from the console. It does not stop after showing this message, but it neither includes the JRE in the jar. A runnable jar is created, however, it uses the system JRE. Thank you for taking a look!

Comment: I've added the build.xml at the bottom of the question

Comment: This looks fine - i guess it is time to file a bug report - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Efxclipse

Comment: I created an empty JavaFX project (which just shows an empty scene), and with this project the build succeeds. It also creates .app, .dmg, and .pkg files. And according to the size, the JRE is included. Any ideas why it doesn't work with my project?

Comment: well this is not a very wild guess but could it be the space in "dist/OctoCash Updater.jar"? In case this does not help please file a bug against efxclipse and we'll solve the problem.

Comment: Maybe your guess is not so wild. I've created a new project named "OctoCashUpdater", and now it works. Asks for code signing, but that is another thing.

Comment: Ok so I guess this still warrants a bug report against e(fx)clipse - we need to get smarter and if the project name holds spaces we need to construct the jar name in a different way. Oh and I never looked into this codesigning thing - it is a fairly new feature in the os-x packager - if there's anything missing please file bugs and we'll fix them ASAP.